# How to get code coverage for new code in Cobertura?

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I have a JAVA project which use Cobertura for code coverage report.
When I implement new code, how could I get the code coverage data for the new code only?

Comment: +1 Interesting idea, not sure how it would work.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. May be using svnkit and and some hacks in cobertura:instrumentation might achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get code coverage on new code with **Sonar**, using **differential views**:

[Code coverage differential http://docs.sonarqube.org/download/attachments/3080855/PeriodsCoverage.png?version=2&modificationDate=1433247329000&api=v2&effects=drop-shadow](http://docs.sonarqube.org/download/attachments/3080855/PeriodsCoverage.png?version=2&modificationDate=1433247329000&api=v2&effects=drop-shadow)

More info there: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views